# Enabling Multiple user shell access on the VM from Vsphere 5.1

Tags: ssh, vmware-esxi, putty, vsphere-client

I have created an ESXI user and enabled shell access in Vshere 5.1 so I can login with the user remotely from Putty. But I get access denied error on entering the ESXI user credentials. Can Someone help me here?

I get below error on Putty

[Error screenshot on Putty when I connect my VM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ucVI.png)End of keyboard-interactive prompts from server
Access denied

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be something to do with character encoding. Try using only ASCII in the password and username and see if it works. Do note that you're talking to the VM, and not the host, so the user configuration needs to be done on the VM, not the host.